# Reading and Displaying lists value trough VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

Please somebody help me in reading values from excel drop down list and copmare these values with the values in the different cells and display results in VBA excel

I have 3 drop down list and i will compare these values with the values in other cells, if it matches i will display the values for that.

I have 2 sheets , Sheet1 and Sheet2. in Sheet1 i have 3 dropdown lists, where i will select the values. When i select these values, i need to search these values in the table exists in the sheet2. And the values to be displayed in a perticular cell. How to do it. Please help

Comment: You will need to add more detail, and to explain what you have tried thus far to receive any feedback on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you maybe look for something like that?

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
If ComboBox1.Value = Range("E3").Text Then
    MsgBox "Same Values"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have Drop down in Lists (excel).